# Issues with some URL's in Multistore Child Store

Tags: magento2, category

I have a store, **mydomain.com**, with a top-level category called Shop accessible via **mydomain.com/shop**.

Its child store, which we'll call "new", is at **new-mydomain.com**. This sub-store also has its own top-level category called "Shop" which I'd like to be accessible via **new-mydomain.com/shop**. In the "new" store view, "shop" has been set as the URL key, but even after all cache clears/reindexes/url regeneration/etc I can only access the category via the longform `/catalog/category/view/s/shop-by-category/id/528/`

Any ideas? Though the URL key is entered as "shop", when I save the category without altering it in any way I receive a

> Something went wrong while saving the category

error, so I'm thinking that could be a clue.

Any thoughts on how to fix this or what to look into would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I had to go into the database and delete the rewrites for Shop in the url_rewrite table (they weren't showing up in the rewrite UI). Once they were deleted, I created rewrites for them via the UI by scoping the store view and setting the target path for the actual category URL.

Still receiving "Something went wrong while saving the category" error, but it seems unrelated.